# get textbox value instead of auto-completion value javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

I have a textbox with jQuery auto-completion feature. What I need is: when I click on the button "Movies by this title", I would like to see the list of movies contain the term in the textbox (even if it is not found in auto-completion), while I see the list of movies by only auto-completion select.

The image below shows the case when I select a movie from auto-completion list (which works well):
[image]

and this is the case when I write just some words (e.g if user forgot the whole name or couldn't find in auto-complete list):

[image]

here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var selected;

$(document).ready(function () {
      $("input[id='selectType']").change(function(){
               if ($(this).val() == "byTitle") {
                    $("#m_scents2").hide();
                    $("#btnMove").show();
                    $("#m_scents").show();
                    $("#q").focus();
                    $("#q").autocomplete({
                        minLength: 0,
                        delay:5,
                        source: "filmsauto.php",
                        focus: function( event, ui ){
                             event.preventDefault(); 
                             return false;
                        },
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                               window.selected = ui.item.value;
                        }
                    });
  }
$('#btnMove').on('click', function (e) {
           popupCenter("movieBytitle.php","_blank","400","400");
  });
```

This is movieBytitle.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var selected = parent.window.opener.selected; 
 $.ajax({
         url: 'childfilm.php',
         datatype: "json",
         data:{p:selected},
         success: function(response) {      
                     $("#field").html(response);
                   }
        });

</script>
```

and this is childfilm.php:

```
if(isset($_GET['p']) && !empty($_GET['p'])){
    include('imdbConnection.php');
    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT movieName, year, posterLink FROM film_info WHERE movieName LIKE :p");
    $query->execute(array(':p' => '%'.$_GET['p'].'%'));
}
?>

<html>
<head>
....
</head>

<body>
 <div class= "movielist"> 
  <table id= "films">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>year</th>
        <th>Title</th>
    </tr>
    <?php while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)): ?>  //THIS IS LINE 53 WHERE THE ERROR IS SHOWN IN THE SECOND IMAGE
    <tr>
        <td><img class='imdbImage' id="image" src='imdbImage.php?url=<?php echo $row['posterLink']; ?>' alt="" /></td>
        <td><label id='year'><?php echo $row['year']; ?> </label></td>

        <td><a href="movie.php?title=<?php echo urlencode($row['movieName']); ?>"><?php echo $row['movieName']; ?></a></td>

    </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  </table>    
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Could someone kindly let me know how I can get the textbox value instead of auto-complete value ??

### UPDATE: FINAL SOLUTION

Since the question is too long and the final solution was achieved in comments, I updated the answer here: Thanks to @lolka_bolka, this finally helped me: change the value of p to --> `($('#q').val())` instead of passing selected auto-complete text.. :)

Comment: i think `matix` is `matrix`. Anyway, it seams, on of your variable is not an object, what you want to use as object. Please show us your `childfilm.php`s line 53. Is it that? `while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):`

Comment: @lolka_bolka: matix is not matrix (i did in intentionally to show if a name is not in auto-complete, I don't get any movie list.. e.g I may only type "The" in the textbox, I would like to see all movies contain "The" (I know it's stupid, but in general I mean the cases when a word in the txtbox is not found in auto-complete list).... for your second question: Yes, this is line 53

Comment: See my answer. You have no `$query` if there are no `$_GET["p"]`, so you can not fetch that object, since, it's not exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Based on OP update, we made the conversation in the comments, please read them.

I think, your problem will be that, if there are not `$_GET["p"]`, then the `$query` won't exists, so you can not use it as an object.

```
<html>
    <head>
        ....
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class= "movielist"> 
            <table id= "films">
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>year</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                if (isset($_GET['p']) && !empty($_GET['p'])) {
                    include('imdbConnection.php');
                    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT movieName, year, posterLink FROM film_info WHERE movieName LIKE :p");
                    $query->execute(array(':p' => '%' . $_GET['p'] . '%'));
                    if ($query->rowCount()) {
                        //If there are no $_GET["p"] then there wont be $query,
                        //So you can not fetch it!!!
                        while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):
                            ?> 
                            <tr>
                                <td><img class='imdbImage' id="image" src='imdbImage.php?url=<?php echo $row['posterLink']; ?>' alt="" /></td>
                                <td><label id='year'><?php echo $row['year']; ?> </label></td>

                                <td><a href="movie.php?title=<?php echo urlencode($row['movieName']); ?>"><?php echo $row['movieName']; ?></a></td>

                            </tr>
                            <?php
                        endwhile;
                    } else {
                        echo '<td colspan="3">Sorry, there are no film like this</td>';
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </table>    
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: :Thanks for your kind help,but I don't want to show the message to the user in case that the term in the textbox was not found in auto-complete.. What I asked in my question, is how to get the textbox value(whatever it is! I don't care if it is not in the auto-complete list).. an example of what I need is what IMDb or amazon do.. if you type a word in the search box in IMDb(even if you DO NOT select from auto-complete list) and just write even "the".., then when you press the "search" button, it will show you list of movies contain term "the"...I hope I could clarify my question:)

Comment: no, it's totally unclear to mee not, what you are trying to achive :) If you want to get the textbox text, then you can use `$('#q').text()` from jQuery. If you want to get it **after** you send the form, then you can access it by `$_POST["q"]` if your form method was `POST` and if it `GET`, then `$_GET["q"];` in PHP. But i think, you know these.

Comment: well, I don't want to get it after I send the form, I want to get it as soon as I click the button "movies by this title".. I tried with `$('#q').val();` before, but I have not tried with `.text()`, so I will do it now and will inform you.. Thanks :)

Comment: Forget it, i was wrong. It should be `.val()` and that should work.

Comment: well, non of them work.. I think my main problem is that I don't know where I have to write `$('#q').val();`

Comment: what is that `popupCenter` function does?

Comment: ah, i see now. At here: data {p:selected}. This is the point, where you somehow neet to get the `$('#q').val();`. So the selected value shold be that.

Comment: it opens a new window (the one you can see list of movies) .. you could see them in images in my question :p

Comment: Yes, i know it opens a new window: just when you call this: `popupCenter("movieBytitle.php","_blank","400","400");` then pass the `$('#q').val()` also, and in your popupCenter function use it as a data. If you can not do this, then somehow, from the new window get the `window.opener.$("#q").val()`